# AngularJS and parsing json with {status code 200..}

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing

I have been trying to research this issue for a couple days now. Finally I have to ask.

I am trying to parse a json api that looks like this with **Angular JS**:

```
{
  "status_code": 200,
  "message": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Rerum provident quisquam iste.",
      "description": "Cumque quidem dolore nulla nostrum ipsa voluptas voluptatem. Tenetur rem maxime necessitatibus numquam quia minus ducimus quia. Reiciendis deserunt quis nihil omnis.",
      "status": 1,
      "created_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50",
      "updated_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "Nemo inventore voluptas quo cumque quod.",
      "description": "Pariatur ipsam in velit officia et odit. Voluptatem consequatur recusandae voluptatum sint soluta praesentium incidunt magni.",
      "status": 1,
      "created_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50",
      "updated_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50"
    },
```

For the life of me I can't figure out how to do this. **All I need is the data [array}**.

I can parse this one just fine. When the array is in a property I can't find seem to get it to work with any of the documentation I find. I am sure I probably have gotten close but I am missing something. Also examples would be greatly appreciated.

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Rerum provident quisquam iste.",
    "description": "Cumque quidem dolore nulla nostrum ipsa voluptas voluptatem. Tenetur rem maxime necessitatibus numquam quia minus ducimus quia. Reiciendis deserunt quis nihil omnis.",
    "status": 1,
    "created_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50",
    "updated_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Nemo inventore voluptas quo cumque quod.",
    "description": "Pariatur ipsam in velit officia et odit. Voluptatem consequatur recusandae voluptatum sint soluta praesentium incidunt magni.",
    "status": 1,
    "created_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50",
    "updated_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50"
  },
```

---

**REVISION FOR CLARITY** This is what I am currently doing.

**HTML** This is inside my ng-app of course and works with the standard array json.

```
        <tr ng-repeat="survey in surveys">
            <td width="100">Survey #{{survey.id}}</td>
            <td>{{survey.title}}</td>
            <td>{{survey.description}}</td>
            <td>{{survey.created_at}}</td>
```

**Angular JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('newsController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.sortType     = 'id'; // set the default sort type
    $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
    $scope.searchSurvey   = '';     // set the default search/filter term
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/survey/api'}).success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.surveys = data; // response data 
    });
 });
```

**This is not working with the json that oupts "{"status_code": 200, ...}"**

Comment: Can you show your code and attempt to parse it? Should just be `response.data`.

Comment: I revised my question to clarify what I was doing @tymeJV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are not accessing the right node of the array, try this

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('newsController', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.sortType     = 'id'; // set the default sort type
    $scope.sortReverse  = false;  // set the default sort order
    $scope.searchSurvey   = '';     // set the default search/filter term
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:8080/survey/api'}).success(function(response)
    {
        $scope.surveys = response.data; // response data 
    });
 });
```

This should work fine.

Comment: Thank you soo much! I figured it was easy but I couldn't find any documentation that made this solution stand out.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how Angular JS differes from normal JS but this is how you can save this in JavaScript (just to give a working example).

***Note:*** There was 1 major issue with the original JSON; you ended it with a comma (`,`) instead of adding the needed `]}` to end the JSON.

```
var name_me = {
    "status_code": 200,
    "message": "success",
    "data": [{
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Rerum provident quisquam iste.",
        "description": "Cumque quidem dolore nulla nostrum ipsa voluptas voluptatem. Tenetur rem maxime necessitatibus numquam quia minus ducimus quia. Reiciendis deserunt quis nihil omnis.",
        "status": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50",
        "updated_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Nemo inventore voluptas quo cumque quod.",
        "description": "Pariatur ipsam in velit officia et odit. Voluptatem consequatur recusandae voluptatum sint soluta praesentium incidunt magni.",
        "status": 1,
        "created_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50",
        "updated_at": "2018-02-20 21:45:50"
    }]
};
```

I hope this answered your question :)

Comment: Oh no... I should have closed with an ellipses. I didn't want to copy the whole code here. The json is valid. It goes to 20 ID's. The JSON data is being generated from my localhost OctoberCMS. I am importing the data via $HTTP Get etc.

Comment: Oh, well in that case... (going off of my example) Have you tried `JSON.parse(name_me)`? I am sorry if you already have but that is all that I am able to think of as of right now. Hope that helps (again)... 